# How to create a new column based on Date Values & Condition in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Table 1:

Item Type          Order Date         Ship  Date            Purchase Cost

0   Example         2014-08-10             2014-08-10             850.7544

1   Snacks          2014-08-10             2014-08-10              NaN

2   Cosmetics        2/22/2015              2/22/2015              NaN

3   Fruits           2015-09-12              2015-09-12            NaN

4   Personal Care    9/17/2014               9/17/2014              NaN

5   Household        2010-04-02              2010-04-02             NaN

6   Clothes          2/20/2013               2/20/2013              NaN

Table 2:

```
Item Type   Purchase Start Date     Purchase End Date   Cost Per Unit
```

0    Baby Food      2010-01-01         2010-05-01               158.2736

1   Beverages       2010-01-01         2010-05-01              36.0620

2   Cereal          2010-01-01         2010-05-01               160.4460

3   Clothes         2010-01-01          2010-05-01              66.6608

4   Cosmetics       2010-01-01          2010-05-01              266.6920

5   Fruits          2010-01-01           2010-05-01             5.5980

6   Household       2010-01-01           2010-05-01             467.7890

7   Meat            2010-01-01           2010-05-01            274.2285

Here I need to fill the Purchase Cost Column In Table 1 Based in Table 2 v Date & Cost Per Unit  Column

For example  In table 1 Household Date  Values between  (2010-04-02 ,2010-04-02) 
so in Table 2 Household Values between  (2010-01-01 ,2010-05-01),so from Table 1  Order Date &  Ship Date are in  the Date range of 'Purchase start Date'& 'Purchase End Date' ,so we can fill the value of Purchase cost as '467.789'  ,So how to fill the Purchase cost ?

Comment: Please beautify the question to give a clear idea

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read and edit your question based on the [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all "date" columns have been converted to *datetime* type.
Otherwise start from converting them.

Generate an auxiliary *Series*:

```
wrk = pricing.assign(year=pricing['Start Date'].dt.year)\
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['Item', 'year'])\
    .set_index(['Item', 'year'])['(USD)dollar'].rename('price'); wrk
```

It contains first price in each year and product.
Product name (*Item*) and *year* are levels of MultiIndex and the price is the value.

For your sample data, completed with one row for *Cosmetics* for year *2014*,
the result is:

```
Item       year
Snacks     2010    68
           2011    72
Cosmetics  2014    50
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Then, to fill *price* column, run:

```
product.price = wrk[product.set_index(['Product',
    product['Date (USD)'].dt.year]).index].tolist()
```

The result is:

```
     Product Date (USD)  price
0     Snacks 2010-02-03   68.0
1     Snacks 2010-02-06   68.0
2     Snacks 2014-02-03    NaN
3     Snacks 2012-02-03    NaN
4  Cosmetics 2012-02-03    NaN
5  Cosmetics 2013-02-03    NaN
6  Cosmetics 2013-02-08    NaN
7  Cosmetics 2014-02-06   50.0
8  Cosmetics 2014-02-09   50.0
```